# What is the lastest working version of VMWare Player on Windows 7 32 bits?

Tags: windows-7, 32-bit, vmware-player

The latest version on their site is 7.0.0 and doesn't work on 7 32 bits. They have a history page on their website with version 2.5 but it doesn't accept recent vmx files.

What is the lastest working version of VMWare Player on Windows 7 32 bits?

My processor is an `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2501 MHz`

[image: vmware player 7.0.0 not installing]

Comment: The Windows version is not enough to answer compatibility questions. The actual CPU is much more important.

Comment: I've added a screenshot which is pretty self-explanatory + cpu info

Comment: `VMware Player 7` is 64-bit only.  This means your limited to using the previous version which would be `VM Player 6` which you have in your folder display in the screenshot.

Comment: I found it on oldapps.com and was reluctant to run it since I have no way to know if the file is genuine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[VMware Player 6](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0|PLAYER-605|product_downloads).

Not sure why you tried to get it from oldapps, it's available from the official site

Comment: Probably because it’s the first page on Google. Guess they did SEO right. :D

Answer (score 4):

The [System Requirements](https://www.vmware.com/products/player/faqs/install-requirements#supported_guest) page indicates that a 64-bit host OS is required, which implies a 64-bit CPU. At the bottom of the page, they say that you can run a 32-bit OS *inside* VM Player which is probably not what you want. They further clarify that **VM Player Plus 6** is the last version to support a 32-bit OS (and CPU) and that you can purchase Player 7 and [downgrade the key](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006975) in order to use Player 6 with a current license and support.

If you want it for personal use, then [VM Player 6.0.7](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0%7CPLAYER-607%7Cproduct_downloads) free (non-Pro, non-trial) is—at the time of this writing—the last version that you can get which will run on a 32-bit CPU.

If you are wondering what features you will be missing out on, you can check the [Release Notes](https://www.vmware.com/support/player/doc/player-712-release-notes.html) of later versions. For the most part, it is just bug- and security-fixes, occasionally adding support for new OSes (e.g., Windows 10), improving performance, changing/adding/improving the virtual hardware devices, and sometimes changing system limits.

In case you concerned about using an older version, notice that VM Player 6.0.7 was released on July 7th, 2015, a full 7 months after version 7.0.0 was released. This shows that they have not completely dropped support for version (32-bit) Player 6 and are, for the time being, providing security-fixes and even [bug-fixes](https://www.vmware.com/support/player60/doc/player-605-release-notes.html). You can also request support for any problems you encounter by posting in the [VMWare Player forums](https://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/player).

Comment: (I’m upgrading VM Player 4 to 6; hopefully the horrible [“jealous child” bug](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2354585) has been fixed since VMP4.)

Answer (score 3):

Like Ramhound already mentioned, VMware decided to drop support for 32-bit versions of Windows in VMware Workstation 11 and VMware Player 7. This also means that support is present up to VMware Workstation 10 and VMware Player 6.

All valid VMware Setup files have a digital signature which you can view and verify in the Right Click → Properties dialog.

[Downloads are available directly from VMware](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0).